# Alien infiltration story in 1960s Analog where aliens with some small deformity take over the secret police

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am trying to identify a short story that appeared in Analog sometime in the 1960s. My memory is a bit hazy, but here goes: The main character is a secret policeman in an Eastern European country. He begins to notice that a number of his new colleagues have a particular physical deformity - I believe it was the shape of their ears, but I may be wrong. He finally comes to understand that these men are aliens and they are taking over the secret police in order to control human society. I think he is killed at the end, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 6):

It’s *The Double-Edged Rope*, by Lloyd Biggle Jr, published in the June 1967 *Analog*,

The main character gets all the way to the Dictator, but then notices something odd about him

> The Glorious Leader rose and walked away. Marzoff’s admiring eyes followed him - - - contemplated his ears, odd-looking ears that seemed sculptured on, in the low relief on the side of his head - - *“You’re not our glorious leader!”* Marzoff blurted - - - ‘. 
> Dmitri Storavieff looked up “Ah, Marzoff. You’re back. - - and what of this mysterious conspiracy?”  “There wasn’t any sir. I’m sorry to have wasted the time.” - - - 
> “What odd ears that man has.” Storavieff thought suddenly. “Strange I never noticed them before.” Ears! - - there was something about ears in the new regulations - - Certain capitalist correspondents were ridiculing the shape of ears among citizens of the southern provinces. - - - Any mention of ears was henceforth to be a criminal offence - - And quite right too - -